# Prop that can be 3 collection types

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I am trying to flow type a react prop `items` which based on route params can be one of 3 collection types. The collections are homogenous.

My type def is: `items: FaqFields[] | HowToVideoFields[] | GuideFields[],`

I am getting errors on this prop type like this:

```
[flow] property `answer` is missing in `HowToVideoFields` [1] but exists in `FaqFields` [2]. (References: [1] [2])
[flow] property `question` is missing in `HowToVideoFields` [1] but exists in `FaqFields` [2]. (References: [1] [2])
[flow] string literal `howTo` [1] is incompatible with string literal `faq` [2] in property `contentType`. (References: [1] [2])
```

and here are each of those field shapes for reference

```
export type SupportCategories = 'SomeCat' | 'SomeOtherCat';

export type FaqFields = {
  answer: string,
  category: SupportCategories[],
  contentType: 'faq',
  id: string,
  question: string,
  slug: string,
  title: string,
};

export type GuideFields = {
  category: SupportCategories[],
  contentType: 'guide',
  id: string,
  slug: string,
  title: string,
};

export type HowToVideoFields = {
  category: SupportCategories[],
  contentType: 'howTo',
  id: string,
  slug: string,
  title: string,
  youtubeId: string,
};
```

Here is how I am using `items`

```
  renderSupportItems(
    items
  ): ?(Element<typeof Accordion> | Element<typeof Masonry>) {
    if (items) {
      if (items.every(i => i.contentType === 'faq')) {
        return (
          <Accordion>
            {items.map(({category, question, answer, id}) => (
              <Accordion.Item key={id}>
                {{
                  label: (
                    <Styled.FaqTitleWrapper>
                      <Styled.FaqEyebrow>
                        <Text tag="h2" theme="newsBody">
                          {category.join(' | ')}
                        </Text>
                      </Styled.FaqEyebrow>
                      <Text tag="h2" theme="narrowBodyLarge">
                        {question}
                      </Text>
                    </Styled.FaqTitleWrapper>
                  ),
                  content: (
                    <Styled.FaqContent>
                      <Text tag="p" theme="newsBody">
                        <Markdown>{answer}</Markdown>
                      </Text>
                    </Styled.FaqContent>
                  ),
                }}
              </Accordion.Item>
            ))}
          </Accordion>
        );
      }

      if (items.every(i => i.contentType === 'guide') || items.every(i => i.contentType === 'howTo')) {
        return (
          <Masonry>{items.map(i => <SupportCard key={i.id} {...i} />)}</Masonry>
        );
      }
    }

    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Hello Chris and welcome to stack overflow. If you want to add information to your question please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51620459/edit) function instead of commenting.

Comment: Can you, please, update the question with how `items` are used in the code where error appear?

Comment: @frontendgirl updated!

Answer (score 0):

My best suggestion (mostly from my experience working with flow) is to slightly change how the `items` are used, and make something as following:

```
renderSupportItems(
    items
  ): ?(Element<typeof Accordion> | Element<typeof Masonry>) {
    if (items) {
      if (items.every(i => i.contentType === 'faq')) {
        return (
          <Accordion>
            {items.map((item) => {
             if (item.contentType === 'faq') {
             const {category, question, answer, id} = item;
             return (<Accordion.Item key={id}>
                {{
                  label: (
                    <Styled.FaqTitleWrapper>
                      <Styled.FaqEyebrow>
                        <Text tag="h2" theme="newsBody">
                          {category.join(' | ')}
                        </Text>
                      </Styled.FaqEyebrow>
                      <Text tag="h2" theme="narrowBodyLarge">
                        {question}
                      </Text>
                    </Styled.FaqTitleWrapper>
                  ),
                  content: (
                    <Styled.FaqContent>
                      <Text tag="p" theme="newsBody">
                        <Markdown>{answer}</Markdown>
                      </Text>
                    </Styled.FaqContent>
                  ),
                }}
              </Accordion.Item>
            ))}
          </Accordion>
        );
        };

        return null;
      }

      if (items.every(i => i.contentType === 'guide') || items.every(i => i.contentType === 'howTo')) {
        return (
          <Masonry>{items.map(i => <SupportCard key={i.id} {...i} />)}</Masonry>
        );
      }
    }

    return null;
  }
```

Even though that from javascript point of view there is no reason to do additional `contentType` check in the `.map` this will make more straightforward for flow with which type exactly it is dealing right now.